# Jenkins SSH authentication: Manually trusted vs. Manually provided keys

Tags: jenkins, ssh

The Github documentation on the Jenkins "[ssh-slaves-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURE.md)" specifies several SSH key verification strategies, two of which are "Manually *provided* key Verification Strategy" and "Manually *trusted* key Verification Strategy".

Manually *provided* key Verification Strategy reads:

> Checks the key provided by the remote host matches the key set by the
> user who configured this connection.
>
> The SSH key expected for this connection. This key should be in the
> form algorithm value where algorithm is one of ssh-rsa or ssh-dss, and
> value is the Base 64 encoded content of the key. The keys should be
> placed in /etc/ssh/<key_name>.pub

Manually *trusted* key Verification Strategy reads:

> Checks the remote key matches the key currently marked as trusted for
> this host.
>
> Depending on configuration, the key will be automatically trusted for
> the first connection, or an authorised user will be asked to approve
> the key. An authorised user will be required to approve any new key
> that gets presented by the remote host.
>
> Require a user with Computer.CONFIGURE permission to authorise the key
> presented during the first connection to this host before the
> connection will be allowed to be established.
>
> If this option is not enabled then the key presented on first
> connection for this host will be automatically trusted and allowed for
> all subsequent connections without any manual intervention.

My question is: if I'm trusting the remote automatically (no need to manually approve the first connection) in the "Manually trusted key Verification Strategy", then what is the actual difference between it and the "Manually provided key Verification Strategy"?

Is it that in the *provided* strategy, the public key must be present in the orchestrator node as well as the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> then what is the actual difference between it and the "Manually provided key Verification Strategy"?

The difference is in the origin of the private SSH key.

### Manually provided key Verification Strategy

You copy the key directly in the option configuration:

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/master/doc/images/hkvs-manual-key.png]

### Manually trusted key Verification Strategy

[image]

(this is the option I usually have enabled)

The key is fetched from the remote server `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: are you sure? does that mean that the agent must hold the private key as well in this strategy? it is already on the master (added as credentials).

Comment: @shibel the agent is only needed if your private key is passphrase protected.

Comment: sorry if I'm being slow. So if I don't have passphrase enabled, basically the only difference is that in manually provided strategy, the private key is simply pasted in the textbox, while in manually trusted it's saved as a credentials object in Jenkins?

Comment: @shibel No, in the second case, the key is the one found on the remote server (hence the need for a Jenkins credential object to connect to the server, using a remote account and its password, in order to access to `~remoteAccount/.ssh/id_rsa`: the private key.

Comment: @shibel That differ from the first case where you don't get the private key by reading it on the remote server, you get it directly in the agent settings, in the SSH Key field.